# Custom DTD should be reachable right?

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

I am working on auditing a client website and they are using a custom DTD for their website and when I try to validate it fails. Then, when I try to hit the dtd directly it is not present.

Should it be?

In the HTML document, it is referenced like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "/web/Business/Resources/10/dtd/xhtml1-transitional-cust1.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

It only needs to be accessible by the validator. It's the responsiblity of the user of the validator to ensure that it has a means to resolve the PUBLIC and/or SYSTEM parts to a DTD file. That might be at the URL of the SYSTEM part, or it might be via a local lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a local file, because that's what the `SYSTEM` part stands for. The validator has no means of finding and reading the custom DTD. What you need is `PUBLIC` followed by a name and a URL.

For the sake of humanity, though. **Don't use custom DTD files without good reason.**

Comment: Why do you discourage of using custom DTD files?